# Thunder Client- How to subtract the numbers from a decimal number

Tags: thunderclient

In my json query

I am using {{ number | subtract(2) }} where if number is 123.40 the result obtained is 121 and values after decimals are trimmed off.

{{ number | subtract(2) }}
number is 123.40
Result 121
Expected Result 121.40